# How to run non-gui Jmeter test with multiple output files

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can i run a non-gui test in Jmeter which have several listeners (PerfMon metrics collector and Summary Report)?
Right now, the command that works for me is with one output file:
[path/to/installation]/jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l summaryResult.csv -j jmeter1.log >jmeter1.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` command line option "tells" JMeter to store results in specified file. You can choose which metrics to store by amending JMeter properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice.`

Defaults are:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>
jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=false
```

You can amend the values:

- by adding relevant lines to *user.properties* file (it's located in /bin folder of your JMeter installation)
- by passing them via `-J` command-line argument like:

  ```
  [path/to/installation]/jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t test.jmx ...
  ```

This way you can control what and how will be stored in your `summaryResult.csv` file. See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting and overriding them.

If you need more than one file, you can additionally use "Filename" input to specify where listener output should go and "Configure" button to choose which metrics you want to store.

[image: Summary Report]